# Trigger Ctrl S on clicking button VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

I have a button

```
<v-btn
 class="mt-2 mb-2 mr-2"
 @click="saveAntennas()"
 >Save</v-btn>
```

In saveAntennas() function, what should be the code, such that on clicking Ctrl + S must be triggered.
Thank You in advance!

Comment: You can't emulate key strikes on the keyboard. What is the exact goal of this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I capture a CTRL-S without jQuery or any other library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11362106/how-do-i-capture-a-ctrl-s-without-jquery-or-any-other-library)

Comment: giving Ctrl + S will execute a set of python scripts and generate files. so I want it to save automatically by clicking a button.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to simulate key press events programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596481/is-it-possible-to-simulate-key-press-events-programmatically)

Comment: You want that on your UI (on your Nuxt page), you click on a button and it does save something (current vue file?) and reload scripts somewhere? If the python scripts are local, then you should handle that on your development workflow configuration (Webpack watcher), like if your file is saved locally on your machine, it triggers some actions. If the python scripts are somewhere else, this should lead to an API call making those actions. The question is poorly phrased tho, because a `ctrl + s` on a page is used to save the current `HTML page` somewhere: out of Vue.js scope, more on an OS level

Comment: No no, its an already developed complex application which executes all these python scripts on pressing Ctrl + S, all I want is instead of pressing Ctrl + S on the keyboard, I want ctrl S to trigger if I click on a button.

Comment: Hehe, please be far more precise as of the environment + context of what you're saying. `which executes all these python scripts on pressing Ctrl + S`, this is a behavior in your code editor, on your local machine, so we're talking about Webpack (/similar) right? Then, please be explicit as of what you want **exactly** because it's quite confusing right now. You cannot save a touched `.vue` file in your VScode from a webpage UI, if it's what you want to achieve. You could save your file in VScode when you lose the focus on your editor (like an `alt + tab` shortcut). Or is it something else?

Comment: I recommend you to look at this interesting discussion: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45568824/listening-to-esc-key-event-on-div-component-in-vue-js

Comment: @FlorentBouisset there is a deleted answer which is regarding the same topic, but this is not what OP wants so far. I'm quoting: "I want that button the execute Ctrl + S, not that on giving Ctrl S the function should execute."

Comment: Saving page using JavaScript is only supported in Internet Explorer (lol): https://stackoverflow.com/a/3530687/6762310